# Append data list view with paging Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I append data lisview when click button **Get more data**?.My is current code only refresh with new data.Thank.
My [code](https://gist.github.com/thaiviethai99/130e2e7578eba626541d929fc9949895):

[Demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB706.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add fullPhotos to keep all photos 
In your original API code return duplicate data at each page 
Because in this API's definition _start is number not page 
so you need to change that part to fit your request

code snippet

```
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client, int page) async {
  print('page la' + page.toString());
  final response = await client.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=' +
          page.toString() +
          '&_limit=2');

  var val = await compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
  print('val.lenght ${val.length}');
  fullPhotos.addAll(val);
  print('fullPhotos  ${fullPhotos.length}');
  return fullPhotos;
}

List<Photo> fullPhotos = [];
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client, int page) async {
  print('page la' + page.toString());
  final response = await client.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=' +
          page.toString() +
          '&_limit=2');

  var val = await compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
  print('val.lenght ${val.length}');
  fullPhotos.addAll(val);
  print('fullPhotos  ${fullPhotos.length}');
  return fullPhotos;
}

List<Photo> fullPhotos = [];
// A function that will convert a response body into a List<Photo>
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Photo {
  final int albumId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  Photo({this.albumId, this.id, this.title, this.url, this.thumbnailUrl});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map json) {
    return Photo(
      albumId: json['albumId'] as int,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      thumbnailUrl: json['thumbnailUrl'] as String,
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  //final String title;
  // MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  int page = 0;
  void _onPressed() {
    setState(() {
      page = page + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo get data'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: _onPressed, child: new Text('Get more data')),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
                  future: fetchPhotos(http.Client(), page),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                    return snapshot.hasData
                        ? PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
                        : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  },
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(1.0, 10.0, 1.0, 10.0),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Photo> photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: photos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Colors.white10,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Image.network(
                          photos[index].thumbnailUrl,
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                        ),
                        title: Text(photos[index].title),
                        subtitle: Text(photos[index].title),
                      ),
                      ButtonTheme.bar(
                        // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                        child: ButtonBar(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                              child: const Text('Open'),
                              onPressed: () {/* ... */},
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but do you have solution append data to list view not use _end param ?

Comment: I have update my code. you need change your api call. your original code return duplicate data at each page